# Counting sum of digits in number

Tags: c#, loops

So, the point is to try and make a program whitch is counting sum of digits in number without cycles and arrays.

```
static uint calc(uint x)
{
    uint ret = 0;
    string xs = x.ToString();
    ret = calc(1, xs);
    return ret;
}

static uint calc(int n, string xs)
{
    uint r = 0;
    r += Convert.ToUInt32(xs[n-1] - '0');
    if (n < xs.Length)
    {
        r += calc(n++, xs);
    }
    return r;
}
        
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    uint a = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    calc(a);
}
```

It makes calls first calc(int n, string xs) but with second it somehow fails and leads to the name of this site (Stack overflow). Can you help me internet ?

Comment: "without cycles" - can you elaborate?

Comment: I`m right now studying recursion and the text of the task is to count sum of digits in natural number N without using strings (sorry about giving already wrong code, translation error), lists, arrays and cycles for() and while().

Comment: "cycles": you probably refer to "loops" (like `for` and `while`)

Comment: Noite that `n++` uses the value of `n` *before* incrementing it. So you basically call `calc` always with n = 1. Hint: there is another increment operator `++n`.

Comment: The classic recursive solution is something like: `uint calc(uint x) => x == 0 ? 0 : x % 10 + calc(x / 10);`

Answer (score 2):

Using string is excessive in your case. Everything you need can be expressed as short as the following.

```
public static uint SumOfDigits(uint n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (n % 10 + SumOfDigits(n / 10));
}
```

What is happening here? First, the number is compared with zero. Then, if it is less than zero, zero is returned. Else, we return a remainder of dividing a number by 10 and adding a recursive call of `SumOfDigits` where we pass our number divided by 10.

How this works? It works because `/` is an [integer division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-) and it returns integer part of resulting number.

Consider calling `SumOfDigits(12)`. The number is greater than zero, so the method will return `12 % 10 = 2` plus call `SumOfDigits(n / 10)`, where `n / 10 = 12 / 10 = 1`. As long as `1` is still greater than zero, you will have `1 % 10 = 1` plus `SumOfDigits(1 / 10)`. As long as `1 / 10 = 0`, `0` is returned. So, `2 + 1 + 0 = 3` which is the answer.

Comment: Or `public static uint SumOfDigits(uint n) => n == 0 ? 0 : (n % 10 + SumOfDigits(n / 10));` to put it short.

Answer (score 1):

Well, loops seems to be inevitable, but you can *hide* them (and have no *explicit* loops), say with a help of *Linq* (having a string `input` let's `Sum` digits, we don't even need to convert to `uint` which allows you to deal with very long numbers):

```
using System.Linq;

...

string input = Console.ReadLine();

int result = input.Sum(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c - '0' : 0);
```

Demo:

```
string[] tests = {
  "",
  "0",
  "123",
  "-123",
  "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
};

static int SumOfDigits(string input) =>
  input.Sum(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c - '0' : 0);

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,50} => {SumOfDigits(test)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
                                               => 0
                                             0 => 0
                                           123 => 6
                                          -123 => 6
      1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 => 180
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want, but be aware that there are no checks if the user enters a non-numeric string.

You can copy and paste the following and run at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        uint sum;
        uint a = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        sum = calc(a);
        Console.WriteLine( "Sum: " + sum );
    }
    
    static uint calc(uint x)
    {
        uint ret = 0;
        string xs = x.ToString();
        ret = calc(0, xs);
        return ret;
    }
    
    static uint calc(int n, string xs)
    {
        uint r = 0;
        if (n < xs.Length)
        {
            r = Convert.ToUInt32( xs[n] - '0' );
            return r + calc(++n, xs);
        }
        return r;
    }
    
}
```